# Dynamix Nginx proxy-pass with a variable from the location path

Tags: nginx, location

What I want to achieve is to use an proxy-pass for a given URL and the proxy-pass domain name depends from the location URL.
Something like this:

```
location ~ ^/([0-9]+)/api/ {
      proxy_pass http://server-$1:8080;
  }
```

logically an URL for example: **/4/api/auth/login**  to use a proxy  **http://server-4:8080/api/auth/login**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already spend my weekend with this issue. But I was able to solve it.
First of all whenever you want to use a variable for constructing the proxy_pass domain you need to use an resolver. More details can be found on this article: https://dev.to/danielkun/nginx-everything-about-proxypass-2ona

And this is how I solved my problem:

```
location ~ ^/([0-9]+)(/api/.*) {
    
    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    proxy_pass http://server-$1:8080$2;

  }
```

If we have a request something like: **https://example.com/1/api/auth/login** 
the pass_proxy will forward the request to: **http://server-1:8080/api/auth/login**